# Transparent grid in IE using jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I'm using jqplot for displaying bar chart and pie chart. I want to display them without grid lines. So, I've inserted the following line.

```
           grid:{background:'transparent',borderColor:'#d0d0d0'},
```

It is not working in IE but in firefox  it is displaying without grid lines. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sur that IE < 9 doesn't support transparancy.

Answer (score 1):

The grid lines can also be removed using the `showGridline` property within the `tickOptions` object (within the x or y axis object [within the axes object {within the options object}]).

```
axes: {
   xaxis: {
      tickOptions: {
         showGridline: false
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for IE <= 8 loading of excanvas, It worked for me:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../src/excanvas.js">   
</script><![endif]-->

grid: {  background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
         drawBorder: false,
         shadow: false
      }
```